# Pandas json_normalize and null values in JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this sample JSON

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
 }
```

When I need to convert JSON to pandas DataFrame I use following code

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pprint import pprint

with open('example.json', encoding="utf8") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
normalized = json_normalize(data['cars'])
```

This code works well but in the case of some empty cars (null values) I'm not possible to normalize_json.

Example of json

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        null,
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
 }
```

Error that was thrown

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I tried to ignore errors in json_normalize, but didn't help

```
normalized = json_normalize(data['cars'], errors='ignore')
```

How should I handle null values in JSON?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fill `cars` with empty dicts to prevent this error

```
data['cars'] = data['cars'].apply(lambda x: {} if pd.isna(x) else x)
```

Answer (score 9):

I agree with vozman, and filling empty `{}` dictionaries will solve the problem. However, I had the same problem for my project and I made a package to work around with this kind of DataFrames. check out [flat-table](https://pypi.org/project/flat-table/), it uses json_normalize but also expands rows and columns.

```
import flat_table
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
flat_table.normalize(df)
```

This will output the following. Lists expanded to different rows and dictionary keys expanded to different columns.

```
   index name_x  age name_y   models
0      0   John   30   Ford   Fiesta
1      0   John   30   Ford    Focus
2      0   John   30   Ford  Mustang
3      1   John   30    NaN      NaN
4      2   John   30   Fiat      500
5      2   John   30   Fiat    Panda
```

Comment: I had some NaN values and this package fixed it perfectly. Thanks @metinsenturk for this PyPi package. It's awesome!

Comment: Thank you  so much @metinsenturk, I have spent and entire day figuring out how to flatten a very nested json and you just saved me another entire day, thank you!!!

Comment: Bravo! Prefer this over `pd.json_noramlize` because I don't have to play around with the "meta" parameter, using `to_dict()`, and as another commentator mentioned: fixing Null values for a complex JSON. It's just plug and play.

Answer (score -1):

How is Another Answer?

```
data['cars'].fillna('{}')
```

Comment: Syscallkkk, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.