# Counting values in nested json read using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count the number of themes after normalizing a nested column.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
0    [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {'code': '11', 'name': ''}]                                                                                                                                                                   
1    [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'}, {'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and risk management'}]                                                                                                                             
2    [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'}, {'code': '2', 'name': 'Public sector governance'}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'Environment and natural resources management'}, {'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and risk management'}]
3    [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/inclusion'}, {'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/inclusion'}]                                                                                                                               
4    [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'}, {'code': '4', 'name': 'Financial and private sector development'}]                                                                                                                        
Name: mjtheme_namecode, dtype: object
```

This is what I have tried:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
result = json_normalize(json_file, 'mjtheme_namecode').name.value_counts()
```

However this returns the error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: list(dict) is in one column? By number of themes you mean?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi yes, by number of themes

Comment: what is theme in you example?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi name in the column mjtheme_namecode

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the way you read the json file, mjtheme_namecode should be one long list, not a list of lists or something like that. Try putting max_level=0. Other possibility is the problem with the empty field. Try putting in a default value (see: [Pandas json_normalize and null values in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050853/pandas-json-normalize-and-null-values-in-json))

I managed to get the result like this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

mjtheme_namecode =[{'code':'8','name':'Humandevelopment'},{'code':'11','name':''},{'code':'1','name':'Economicmanagement'},{'code':'6','name':'Socialprotectionandriskmanagement'},
                   {'code':'5','name':'Tradeandintegration'},{'code':'2','name':'Publicsectorgovernance'},{'code':'11','name':'Environmentandnaturalresourcesmanagement'},{'code':'6','name':'Socialprotectionandriskmanagement'},
                   {'code':'7','name':'Socialdev/gender/inclusion'},{'code':'7','name':'Socialdev/gender/inclusion'},
                   {'code':'5','name':'Tradeandintegration'},{'code':'4','name':'Financialandprivatesectordevelopment'}]
print(mjtheme_namecode)

result = json_normalize(mjtheme_namecode).name.value_counts()
print(result)
```

```
Socialdev/gender/inclusion                  2
Socialprotectionandriskmanagement           2
Tradeandintegration                         2
Humandevelopment                            1
Publicsectorgovernance                      1
Environmentandnaturalresourcesmanagement    1
Financialandprivatesectordevelopment        1
Economicmanagement                          1
                                            1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: mjtheme_namecode for me is a list of dict. Could you provide json example that you read so that I can see why it is a column in a dataframe for you? Can you try to read it in a dict ?