# Unnesting json data from a DataFrame with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python. I have a simple DataFrame with a .json string I'd like to unnest.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([None, {'name': 'Charlie'}], columns=['A'])
pd.json_normalize(df, record_path=['A'], meta=['name'])
```

The following is giving me a "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error.

I have not had any luck with similar fixes such as making my `df` into a dict[1] or by using a lambda function[2].

[1] [Python: json normalize "String indices must be integers" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710154/python-json-normalize-string-indices-must-be-integers-error)

[2] [Pandas json_normalize and null values in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050853/pandas-json-normalize-and-null-values-in-json)

Comment: I wanted the column to be replace by the values. Thanks @not_speshal that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df["A"].fillna("").apply(dict).tolist())
```